# Cannot pause or unpause a DAG in Airflow UI

Tags: airflow

I am facing an issue in Airflow UI where I cannot pause or unpause a DAG. I see this 400 error in browser network console. This seem to just happen in recent build of Airflow. I've been using version 1.10.10.

```
jquery-latest.js:2 POST https://localhost:8080/paused?is_paused=true&dag_id=test_dag 400
```

Comment: Weird, try changing your logging_level to `DEBUG` in your airflow.cfg file, that usually helps narrow it down.

Comment: In my case the request was blocked by AdBlock.

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading the version of Flask-Appbuilder to 2.3.2

```
pip install -U "Flask-AppBuilder==2.3.2"
```

Related Github issues:

- https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/8599
- https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/8613

Comment: Will the downgrade results to other issues?

Comment: No, it should be fine.